# Python: Retrieving color codes from a number input by user

Tags: python, input, colors, calculation

I am working on a school project where we are supposed to retrieve three color codes (for red, green and blue) from a number between 0-16777215 (because 256x256x256=16777216). I am unable to understand how this number can produce three color codes.

The following code was part A of the task, which I have resolved:

```
background = input ('Choose background color:')
innersq = input ('Choose color of inner square:')

# set up drawing
setup(330, 330, 0, 0)
screensize(315, 315)
goto(-60, 150)

# choosing colors
bgcolor(background)
color(innersq)
```

This code was made so that the user would enter a color green, blue, red etc.

The new code is supposed to get the input 0-16777215 and calculate a color code for each of the three main colors.

The last part of the code should end up something like this:

```
#choosing colors
bgcolor(Rb0-255, Gb0-255, Bb0-255)
color (Rb0-255, Gb0-255, Bb0-255)
```

Comment: My problem is in getting the input number to produce three color codes

Answer (score 1):

This is one standard representation for a color.  Think of the input as being in binary or hexadecimal, rather than decimal.  The first 8 bits are the `red` part, the middle 8 bits are the `green` part, and the last 8 bits are the `blue` part.

You'll likely want to use integer division to move the wanted part to the right side of your number, then use the modulus operator, `%`, to grab the eight bits needed.  Another way to attack the same idea is to use the bit-wise and operator, `&`, to get those last bits.

That should be enough of a hint to get you moving.

Comment: I don't understand. It would be very helpful if you would tell me the math of how to get the desired colorcode-numbers from the input number